# Simple SQL query on a small table is hung in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a DB table 'signal_constants' in Oracle 12C. Following is the issue I came across today. Please let me know what could be the root cause of this and how to resolve this.

```
select count(*) from signal_constants;
=> 200

select name, value from signal_constants;
=> <no response, query is hung>
```

Comment: Please add explain planS for these two queries

Comment: I would check to see if your database session is active or not - if you can't do this yourself, ask your DBA.

Comment: Most probably you have a table with 200 rows that allocats a large (unsued) space. This can be due to tons of `insert`s followed by `delete`s. `Count(*)` works fine a using index, but select must `FULL SCAN` the whole unused space. Check table statistics (dba_tables.BLOCKS) if statistics are up to date or `DBA_SEGMENTS` to see the actual table size. You would need a reorg of the table to reset the `HWM`.

Comment: This happened due to archive logs. Resolved now, so closing this.